# PHP error: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

I received this error when I run my code.

Error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\SearchEngine\search.php on line 11

Code:

```
<?php
    //php code goes here
    include 'connect.php'; // for database connection
    include 'script_suggestion.php';
    include 'script_close_suggestion_box.php';
    $query = $_GET['q']; // query
    $button = $_GET ['submit'];

    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $page_number = (int)$_GET['page'];
        $page_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($page_number);
    }
    else
        $page_number = 1;

    $results_per_page = 3;

?>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should use prepared statements, not manual escaping, anyways

Answer (score 1):

If you use procedural style

```
mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```

More: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

the syntax you wrote is for `mysql_real_escape_string`.in `mysqli_real_escape_string` u have to add link also.   the correct syntax is:

```
string mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )
```